# How to install a VFP 9 Application on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to install a Visual Fox Pro 9 application on a Windows Server 2012 server running on Amamzon EC2. I'm not sure exactly how to achieve this. Can someone give me specifics? The application is meant to be used by several users running windows 7 or 8.1.

Comment: Impossible to say with that level of detail. Does it have an installer, i.e. setup.exe? Does it have instructions? Where did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Although VFP can be written to act as a COM server (exe or dll), typically the applications are written as stand-alone executable files and would be run on a user's local machine, just have the actual data common on the server that the application will point to during execution.  There are a few basic files you need for VFP to run including VFP9.exe, VFP9R.ENU, VFP9R.dll (others if different language set).

That said, can you clarify what you are doing with the VFP 9 app?  Such as do you have a web-service using IIS / ISAPI or other web-based tools that the VFP is acting to serve up web pages